# Configure Apache TLSv 1.2

Tags: apache, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to configure apache to support only TLSv1.2 Ciphers.
I tested in DEV server and below configuration working fine.

```
vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
```

Added below lines.

```
SSLCipherSuite DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-
               SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
```

The `nmap scan` output is as below,
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 abc.xyz.com
Starting Nmap 6.40 at 2017-07-31 12:02 GMT
Nmap scan report for abc.xyz.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.0022s latency).

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd 2.4.7 ((Ubuntu))
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   SSLv3: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
```

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.53 seconds

---

when i do the same (apache ssl.conf) settings in the stage server the output is different.
I have also added "SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2" in apache virtualhost config file.

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 localhost
```

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-31 12:05 GMT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000064s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http Apache httpd 2.4.7 ((Ubuntu))
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   SSLv3: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.43 seconds
```

My Apache version is  : `Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`
My OpenSSL version is : `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`
Above versions are same on stage & dev servers.

Can any one guide me, whats going wrong in stage server?

Comment: Check the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/848177/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-apache), looks like the same case.

Comment: It work , but web application / url doest not load in Browser.

Comment: What does it show? Do you receive any error in website logs?

Comment: Tested using chrome browser which supports tls v1.2.

Comment: Working fine, The issue with stage server was Load Balancer config. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when multiple `SSLProtocol` directive is used in several configs. Solution is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/848177/how-can-i-disable-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-apache).

Comment: Thanks you for your support, This may help : This issue was at Load Balancer. "We found load balancer was not configured to support / redirect ciphers info".